# Embedding jquery calendar plugin--nothing showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, embed

I am attempting to embed this jquery calendar into my webpage
http://www.jplugins.net/pretty-calendar/?demo

I am following the directions listed here:
https://www.apptic.me/blog/making-pretty-calendars-with-jquery.php

While I have pasted everything listed here for the basic functioning into my document (including the sample script) nothing is showing up.  Any insights?  Here is the relevant code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.apptic.me/projects/calendar/pretty-calendar-minified.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.apptic.me/projects/calendar/pretty-calendar-minified.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="navWrap" style="width:70%;height:80%;position:absolute;top:10%;margin:0 auto;right:0;left:0;"></div>

<script>
var events = [];
events[0] = [];
events[0][0] = "Sunday";
events[0][1] = "3:00pm";
events[0][2] = "Just a sample event"
events[0][3] = "#c0c0c0";
events[1] = [];
events[1][0] = "Monday";
events[1][1] = "12:00pm";
events[1][2] = "Another event"
events[1][3] = "#8FD8D8";

var prettyCal = new PrettyCalendar(events, "navWrapper");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you have the ID "navWrap" but then you try to call the function with "navWrapper".

Comment: Ahh strange!  Thanks for noticing this.  I changed it to navWrapper to match but still no luck.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't think so...I added an alert to make sure the JS was functioning and the alert popped up.  At this point I'm not even concerned with the functionality, I'm just trying to make it appear on the page.

Comment: I copy and pasted your exact code not adding anything but only changing "navWrap" to "navWrapper" and created an html file. I loaded it with http-server and it worked.

Comment: Wow thanks!  Must be a server thing then; I was only using the local copy.  Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if PrettyCalendar has a server requirement but it's difficult to load the jQuery CDN when it begins with //. If you want to try to make it work locally add http: in front of it.